# Check if content of file has length X and contains only specific characters

Tags: shell, string

Let's say, I have files that contain only one docker id:

`myid.id`:

```
28fe2baadbe8da32ed0b99c69b11c01b2d141bc5b732b81e0960086de52fc891
```

I want to check if the content of `my.id` is exactly `64` characters long and contains only characters in the range [0-9] and [a-z] (maybe [a-f]).

- How can I do that?
- If the file contains a newline `0x0a`, how can I include/exclude it in this check?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try:

```
$ echo 28fe2baadbe8da32ed0b99c69b11c01b2d141bc5b732b81e0960086de52fc891 | 
awk '{sub(/\r/,"")} length == 64 && /^[[:xdigit:]]+$/'
28fe2baadbe8da32ed0b99c69b11c01b2d141bc5b732b81e0960086de52fc891
```

or use `perl` instead.

Include newline:

```
perl -ne 'print if length == 64 and /^[[:xdigit:]]+$/'
```

Exclude newline:

```
perl -nle 'print if length == 64 and /^[[:xdigit:]]+$/'
```

Comment: Thank you. Can you also answer the added second question that I just encountered?

Comment: @1_CR well that's exactly my problem right now :D

Comment: it doesn't work somehow. `awk 'length==64 && /^[[:xdigit:]]*/` did work. Mind the `*`.

Comment: @polym: You must use `+` instead of `*`. Try the fixed. I don't know why the first does not work?

Comment: nope still doesn't work, weird. `echo 'df79b8640f3198bcd80937e8c089fe5c5fc5fc3cba56d129f3f7b7084362f258' | awk '{sub(/\r/,"")} length == 64 && /^[[:xdigit:]]+/'` does produce nothing.

Comment: @polym: Yes, because your string is 65 characters long?

Comment: sorry, added a 0. still without the 0 and 64 chars long, won't work :(.

Comment: @polym: Does the `perl` solution work?

Comment: yes the second one works perfectly and is quick. thanks :)

Comment: BTW: in perl, `... if /^[[:xdigit:]]{64}$/` should do it. You can put the length in the regex.

Answer (score 5):

How about a whole-line grep

```
grep -qxE '[[:xdigit:]]{64}' myid.id && echo "yes"
```

or (not sure about this one) bash-specific

```
IFS= read -r id < myid.id 
[[ ${#id} -eq 64 ]] && [[ $id =~ [[:xdigit:]]{64} ]] && echo "yes"
```

Comment: Or `grep -qE '^[[:xdigit:]]{64}$' myid.id`.

Answer (score 2):

```
read s <./file
[ ${#s} -eq 64 ] &&
[ -n "${s##*[![:alnum:]]*}" ] && 
echo success\!
```

If you decide to restrict the test to *a-f* then change `[:alnum:]` to `[:xdigit:]`. Though it's worth mentioning that any application using the POSIX classes `[:alnum:]` *and/or* `[:xdigit:]` will match `A-[ZF]` as well - it's part of the spec... If that's a problem you might want to add one more test like:

```
...&& [ -n "${s##*[[:upper:]]*}" ] &&...
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this out:

```
 echo 28fe2baadbe8da32ed0b99c69b11c01b2d141bc5b732b81e0960086de52fc891 | grep [:0-9a-z:] |  wc -c
```